# Compare two unsorted files line by line and only output lines which are in file 1 AND file 2, but not in file 1

Tags: php, python, grep

I need to Compare two unsorted files line by line and only output lines which are in file 1 AND file 2, but not in file 1. Essentially giving me New + Same strings from each of the two files, and excluding the old/non-existing strings.

I need to do this on some very large files. (10+ GB)(About 1,000,000 lines).

I have tried a few of the below options, but nothing gives me exactly what I need:

```
join -v1 -v2 <(sort File1.txt) <(sort File2.txt) > File3.txt
```

This "join" seems to give me the lines that are in both File1.txt AND/OR File2.txt. (Essentially giving me a combine+unique command). (This is almost correct, but I need this to exclude the the lines/strings if they are not in the second file, but are in the first file.

```
fgrep -vf File1.txt File2.txt > File3.txt
```

This works but as you know, is Very slow on large files and is not really an option.

Case sensitivity would be nice, but not at all required. The reason I mention this is because in my research I found that if the compare was case insensitive, it would speed up the search a Lot.

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: Say for example each file contains a list of random absolute URL's

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence. How can a line be in file 1 and file 2 but not in file 1?

Comment: To see `lines which are in file 1 AND file 2, but not in file 1` just do `cat /dev/null`. To see `New + Same strings from each of the two files, and excluding the old/non-existing strings` just do `cat file2`. THINK about it and then edit your question to tell us what you really want and provide sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear what you are trying to do but try this:

```
comm <(sort File1.txt) <(sort File2.txt)
```

and `man comm` for whatever arguments you need.